# Ng pattern to accept pipe separated input in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I have a form and I want to accept pipe separated values for a particular field only in the format

**4 digits|8digits|any number of digits.**

I tried using  `^\d{1,6}(|\d{1,6}){3}`

But this is wrong.

Comment: The pipe `|` is a special character in regular expressions. You need to escape it with a backslash, otherwise the regex engine will treat it as a logical OR.

Answer (score 1):

Try `\d{4}\|\d{8}\|\d*` if the `any number of digits` can be 0, if not, then try `\d{4}\|\d{8}\|\d+`